# Java / Searching, modifying and removing elements from Array List of user defined classes

Tags: java, search, arraylist, graph-theory, getter-setter

I have an Array List of directed graph edges.

```
List<Edge> graph = new ArrayList();
```

I know that I can use `HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>` for an adjacency list representation of directed graphs for faster O(n) performance, but `List<Edge>` is just an example for clarifying my question for other similar Array List of user defined objects.

Edge is user defined class as follows:

```
public class Edge
{
    int sourceVertex;
    int destinationVertex;

    public int getSourceVertex()
    {
        return sourceVertex;
    }

    public int getDestinationVertex()
    {
        return destinationVertex;
    }

    public void setSourceVertex(int sourceVertex)
    {
        this.sourceVertex = sourceVertex;
    }

    public void setDestinationVertex(int destinationVertex)
    {
        this.destinationVertex = destinationVertex;
    }
}
```

We can add new elements to the directed graph Array List by creating new objects of edge class.

```
Edge edge = new Edge();
edge.setSourceVertex(1);
edge.setDestinationVertex(2);
graph.add(edge);
```

My question is that whether it is possible to search, modify or remove elements from directed graph Array List just by specifying the source vertex and destination vertex, without examining every element of the Array List. We do not know the index of any particular element in the directed graph Array List to be able to do those operations in the directed graph Array List by index.

Whether those search and modify operations will be possible at least in O(log n) time, without taking O(n) time if I am allowed to make use of Array List representation of directed graph edges only?

Answer (score 0):

Searching in O(log n) time is always possible via **Binary search**.
Start in the middle of the list, if the value of the property is smaller or bigger than what you want to find, then cut here and go to the half of the left side or right side.

### A rough outline

You will need some kind of order in the list to achieve O(log n) performance.
Something like this:
Ordered by source and then by target:

```
{
    // all with source=1
    Edge(src=1, target=1),
    Edge(src=1, target=2),
    Edge(src=1, target=4),
    // all with source=2
    Edge(src=2, target=2),
    // all with source=3
    Edge(src=3, target=2),
    // all with source=4
    Edge(src=4, target=2)
}
```

Finding a specific edge with a specified src is possible via binary search. But if you would want to search for a specific target, then this wouldn't work sind the list is sorted by source - you will have to reorder! (see bottom).

To insert the edges on the correct index in O(log n) time, also use binary search and then insert the new edge via

```
graph.add(index, edge);
```

If you would want to get all edges with a specific destination, then you would have to reorder the arrayList (which takes O(log n) with good sort-algorithm like Mergesort or Heapsort) and then you could do the same as above.

Reorder your array via:

```
Collections.sort(arrayList, 
                        (o1, o2) -> o1.getDestination().compareTo(o2.getDestination()));
```

...or whatever property you would want to sort by.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using `HashMap<Integer, Set<Integer>>` as a representation of the graph?

Or, you can add `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods to your `Edge` class and use something like `Set<Edge> edges = new HashSet<>();` and standard methods from `Set` interface in Java.

All the operations (add/remove edge) will use `O(1)` runtime complexity.

Comment: Yes, but my question is not about efficient representations of any given graph, but how can we efficiently search, modify or remove elements from an Array List (or Hash Set) of user defined classes by using one of the variable values in the user defined class.

Comment: I just used graph as an example to specify a user defined class to ask my question, but it can be some other user defined class also. May be that the graph theory tag might not be relevant enough for my asked question.